# Can a textbox be expanded to enter in multi line text?

Tags: c#, textbox, expand

I am coding a C# forms application and I have a multi line textbox. Does the textbox have an inbuilt feature to have a button to the right of the control, that expands the textbox so that text can be entered in a large textbox area.

I am referring to the type of action in this image:

[image]

If not, how is the best way to code this?

Thanks.

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible :-) What have you tried?

Comment: Is there an inbuilt feature to perform this action? Or does this need to be coded manually?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is not, you have to code it yourself

Comment: How would be the best approach to do this?

Comment: It really depends on you requirements how to do it. Do you want to reuse it? Is there an option to shrunk it down again once you expanded it? Etc...

Comment: I do want to reuse it and I would like to be able to shrink it down once it has been expanded. Is there some example code that can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a button to your project, double click on it and use the following:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(newWidth, newHeight);
    }
```

That button should make the textbox bigger. If you want to shrink it back again after you click on it while it's expanded it'd be a simple matter of adding a boolean and checking it every time you click on the button (and change its status, of course).